# How to reset countdown between switching back and forth React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an app with two pages which both displaying a [countdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component). Each countdown when displayed starts with an value which was configured at the beginning. If the countdown who is currently displayed reaches zero the page with the other countdown gets displayed. It's supposed to go back and forth. I am able to switch between the two pages but I don't know how to reset the countdown. In my case the countdown reaches zero and does not start again when switching back and forth.

**Page one**

```js
const Page1 = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <CountDown
        size={40}
        until={someValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning}
        timeToShow={["S"]}
        onFinish={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Page2");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Page two**

```js
const Page2 = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <CountDown
        size={40}
        until={someValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning}
        timeToShow={["S"]}
        onFinish={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Page1");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

How can I modify the code that always when switching back and forth `someValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning` gets used in the counter and not zero once the countdown has run down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I just created an global state where I increase the stored variable on every `onFinish` by one. Through the state update the whole component is rerendered.

```js
const Page1 = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [rerender, setRerender] = useContext(Renderer); /*init of global state*/
  return (
    <View>
      <CountDown
        size={40}
        until={someValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning}
        timeToShow={["S"]}
        onFinish={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Page2"); setRerender(rerender+1) 
        }} /*increase global state on every onFinish by one*/
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Page two**

```js
const Page2 = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <CountDown
        size={40}
        until={someValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning}
        timeToShow={["S"]}
        onFinish={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Page1");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation listener to know when screen has been changed

```
const [SomeValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning, setSomeValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning] = useState(90)

    useEffect(() => {
        //create a listener everytime your screen is not focus and reset your countdown
        navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
            //here set your state to the original value;
            SetSomeValueConfiguredAtTheBeginning(90);
        });
    
        return () =>{
            //when component will unmounted remove the listener
            navigation.removeListener('blur', () => {}); 
        };
     }, [navigation]);
```